# python Telnet through a SSH tunnel

Tags: python, networking, ssh, telnet

I wrote a python script that will start an SSH session, and afterwards it will Telnet into a switch. using pexpect, pxssh and telnetlib.

everything seems to be working and I am able to access some switches. but for the majority I get this error:

**socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused**

OR sometimes:

**NO ROUTE TO HOST**

I checked, there is a server listening on the default port, and my firewall is turned off.

- as a note there are no restrictions on the switch, and my IP is whitelisted*

also what seems off, when I try to use SSH and TELNET commands outside the script (in shell), everything will work and I can access the switch.

I would appreciate any feedback.

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import sys
import telnetlib
s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = ('#')
username = ('##')
password = ('###')

#LOGIN TO SSH HOST
s.login(hostname,username,password)

user=('####')
passw=('#####')
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.read_until("username: ")
tn.write(user+"\n")
tn.read_until("password: ")
tn.write(passw+"\n")
tn.write("terminal length 0\n")
tn.write("show interface description\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
data = tn.read_all()
print data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH isn't really a tunnel itself; it's an application layer protocol. Telnet, which is also an application layer protocol, needs at least TCP layer tunnel. If you want to telnet **inside** SSH, you need to use `telnet` command on the remote server via SSH instead.

```
from pexpect import pxssh

s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = ('#')
username = ('##')
password = ('###')
s.login(hostname,username,password)

s.sendline('telnet [your hostname]')
s.sendline('show interface description\n')
```